# Allowing Apostrophe in Javascript Function from HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I want to call a Javascript funnction from HTML below:

```
 <button data-toggle="modal" onclick="load_data('<%= data.book.to_json %>')">Click</button>
```

Here `data.book.to_json`  is the JSON, which I am passing.

One of my key contains an apostrophe value like `{"key": "value's"}`
which gives me the error like:

> SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list.

If I remove the apostrophe like `{"key": "value"}`, then it works.

And, I want to use apostrophe. So, please let me know how to do this.

I tried with \' before the JSON object but it doesn't works.

Comment: Have you tried with equivalent code i.e. `&#39;` ?

Comment: where ? '<%= data.book.to_json %>

Comment: What is the actual markup received by the browser? Is it `onclick="load_data({"key":"value's"})"`? See the issue with the quotes?

Comment: <button onclick="load_data('{&quot;shipping_method&quot;:null,&quot;comments&quot;:&quot;sada's}')">

Comment: similar to onclick="load_data({"key":"value's"})"

Answer (score 1):

And like this?

```
<button data-toggle="modal" onclick="load_data(#{data.book.to_json})">
```

And this:

```
 <button data-toggle="modal" onclick='load_data("#{data.book.to_json}")'>
```

Comment: I have tried onclick="load_data('<%= #{data.book.to_json} %>')" but it is not working

Comment: What does the rendered HTML element look you?

Comment: updated the code... should be something like this, play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps use this way

```
JSON.stringify(data.book).replace(/'/g, "&#39;")
```

or may be

```
data.book.to_json.replace(/'/g, "&#39;")
```

I have not tried the latter. But I think it would work.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You may try PHP `addslashes` functionality equivalent in Rails.
It will add backslash before escaped characters like single quote ('), double quote ("), backslash ().

Clik here for  [PHP addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the error by creating a callback in the model:

```
after_find do
    self.comments = (self.comments.gsub("'","&#39"))
end
```

It will replace  the single quote by &#39 while fetching the record.I just make the changes in the column which is accepting single quotes .
Thanks all for your valuable suggestions.